# Unable to enable the "View on Site" functionality in SDL Web 8.5

Tags: dxa, web8.5, cme, dxa-2.0

In our implementation, we are unable to enable the "View on Site" functionality in SDL Web 8.5.

The option, whenever clicked for any page re-directs to a localhost path - http://localhost:8080/group/newsletter/index.html etc., 
which I am not sure where I could update to set it to our web page path - http://abcdef.esssa.com/group/newsletter etc..

Is there any config file which needs to be updated with the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To work with **View on Site** functionality you need to configure your website URLs to Create the Website and Web Application into Topology Manager.

```
Add-TtmWebsite -Id Staging_Website -CdEnvironmentId StagingCdEnvironment -Baseurls @("http://abcdef.esssa.com", "http://localhost:8080")
```

please change your customer environment websiteId and CdEnvironmentId

**Note:**

View on site functionality always refers to the first base URL from the above configuration if you have multiple base URLs configured.

I hope it helps